# How do you copy every cell, which contains a number, from two non-adjacent cols and the cells to that left of those cells and paste into one new Col

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, foreach, offset

For various reasons, I need a macro that opens a separate workbook and pulls the cells from two different columns (D and I) that fit a criteria (contains a number), as well as the cell to the left of said number containing cell (C and H) and paste all of that into 2 columns (as opposed to 4) in a new workbook.  C and H contain Text when next to a D or I column cell which contains a number.  Cells in columns D and I can contain numbers, text or be blank.  Then I need those to be pasted into the workbook that contians the macro into 2 columns (AT and AU) starting in cell AT2.

I have a dialogue box that prompts the user to select the workbook needed (as it will change several times throughout the year) for the source data.  Where the code gets hung up is when at Set copyrng = (sell:selloff), it's giving me a syntax error.  I wanna say that the issue is that I haven't "Set sell" to anything but I'm not sure what I need to set it to since it will not be a singular cell. I'm pretty new to VBA and have mostly been getting things off of the internet and adapting it to suit my needs.

I haven't been able to get the code to run so far due to the syntax error.

```
Dim Filename As String
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim Message As String: Message = "Would you like to import new data?"
    Dim Ans
        Ans = MsgBox(Message, vbYesNo)
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    If Ans = vbYes Then
        
     Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
     With fldr
        .Title = "Select Current Data Sheet"
        .Show
        
        Dim FolderPath As String
        If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
            FolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "Please select a file, even if it's the old one.  Otherwise, hit No on the first prompt"
        
        End If
     End With

        FolderPath = fldr.SelectedItems(1)
        Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsx")
        
        Dim UNdest As Variant
        Dim sell As Range
        Dim selloff As Range
        Dim copyrng As Range
        Dim dastination As Range
        
        Set UNdest = Workbooks("Master Tracker").Sheets("Data").Range("AT2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        
           
        Do While Filename <> ""
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
            Workbooks(Filename).Activate
            
            For Each sell In Range("D:D")
                If IsNumeric(sell.Value) Then
                    Set selloff = sell.Offset(-1, 0)
                    Set copyrng = (sell:selloff)
                    copyrng.Copy UNdest
                Else 'should be skipping the cell if it doesn't contain a number
                End If
            Next sell
            
            Workbooks(Filename).Close
            Filename = Dir()

        Loop
    
    Else
    End If
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Sorry if the code is messy or confusing.  I have very little coding experience in general and have been trying to use VBA to make our operation run more smoothly.  Therefore, I've been really copy pasting and modifying from different forums answering questions as opposed to trying to learn for comprehension.  Hopefully, I'll get to that one day.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Try `Set copyrng = Range(sell, selloff)` OR `Set copyrng = sell.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(2, 1)`

Comment: *due to the syntax error* - **What** syntax error? You've not said anything about a syntax error other than that, and have not included the error message you're getting or indicated where that syntax error is located (which is highlighted when the error occurs).

Comment: If `D=1` and `I=2`, and `C="a"` and `H="b"`, what should land in `AT` and `AU`? `"1a"` and `"2b"`? What is the (tab) name of the source worksheet (the one being copied from)? Is this code in workbook `"Master Tracker.xlsm"`?

Comment: @KenWhite the Syntax error is highlighting Set copyrng = (sell:selloff) in the debug.  I believe Derby 9421 has solved.  Thank you for your response

Comment: @VBasic2008 1 & 2 would end up in the AT column, a & b would land in the AU column. So, in the source workbook, if D7 is the first cell that contains a number, the macro should copy D7 and C7 and paste into AT2 and AU2 in the new workbook.  It should do that for all cells in the D column that contain a number, then continue with the I column.  If I8 was the first cell in the I column to have a number, it would copy I8 & H8 and paste in the next blank cells in the AT and AU cells respectively.

the source workbook is user defined and the worksheet would always be called "Raw"

Comment: What is the name of the workbook containing this code? Is it the destination workbook `"Master Tracker.xlsm"`? Is the path of the source workbooks somehow in relation to the path of the destination workbook, e.g. if the latter is `C:\Test`, maybe the former is `C:\Test\Source`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 that destination workbook is "Master Tracker.xlsm" and is in a completely different directory . e.g. `C:\Admin\Source` and `L:\Data\Tracking`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Import Data From Multiple Files

**Main**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportData()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Import Data"
    Const INI_QUESTION As String = "Would you like to import new data?"
    Const INI_CANCELED As String = "Operation canceled!"
    Const FOLDER_TITLE As String = "Select Current Data Sheet"
    Const FOLDER_CANCELED As String = "Folder dialog canceled!"
    Const NO_FILES_FOUND As String = "No files found!"
    Const SRC_FiLE_PATTERN As String = "*.xlsx"
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Raw"
    Const SRC_FIRST_ROW As Long = 2
    Dim sCols() As Variant: sCols = VBA.Array("D", "C", "I", "H")
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Data"
    Const DST_FIRST_ROW As Long = 2
    Dim dCols() As Variant: dCols = VBA.Array("AT", "AU")

    Dim Answer As Long:
    Answer = MsgBox(INI_QUESTION, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, PROC_TITLE)
        
    If Answer = vbNo Then
        MsgBox INI_CANCELED, vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim FolderPath As String:
    FolderPath = PickFolder(, FOLDER_TITLE, , FOLDER_CANCELED)
    If Len(FolderPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim Filename As String: Filename = Dir(FolderPath & SRC_FiLE_PATTERN)
    If Len(Filename) = 0 Then
        MsgBox NO_FILES_FOUND, vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dws.Cells(DST_FIRST_ROW, dCols(0))
    
    Dim dUpper As Long: dUpper = UBound(dCols)
    Dim sUpper As Long: sUpper = UBound(sCols)
         
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 0 To dUpper
        dcell.EntireRow.Columns(dCols(n)) _
            .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - DST_FIRST_ROW + 1).ClearContents
    Next n
    
    Dim swb As Workbook, sws As Worksheet, srg As Range, scell As Range
    Dim Data1() As Variant, Data2() As Variant
    Dim srCount As Long, sr As Long, dr As Long
    Dim IsSheetFound As Boolean, IsDataFound As Boolean, WasCleared As Boolean
       
    Do While Len(Filename) > 0
        Set swb = Workbooks.Open( _
            Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)
        On Error Resume Next
            Set sws = swb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
        On Error GoTo 0
        IsSheetFound = Not sws Is Nothing
        If IsSheetFound Then
            IsSheetFound = False ' reset
            With sws.Cells(SRC_FIRST_ROW, sCols(0))
                srCount = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, .Column) _
                    .End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
                If srCount > 0 Then
                    Set srg = .Resize(srCount)
                    IsDataFound = True
                End If
            End With
        End If
        If IsDataFound Then
            IsDataFound = False ' reset
            For n = 0 To sUpper Step dUpper + 1
                Set srg = srg.EntireRow.Columns(sCols(n))
                dr = 0 ' reset
                Data1 = GetRangeSingleColumn(srg)
                Data2 = GetRangeSingleColumn(srg.EntireRow _
                    .Columns(sCols(n + 1)))
                For sr = 1 To srCount
                    If VarType(Data1(sr, 1)) = vbDouble Then
                        dr = dr + 1
                        Data1(dr, 1) = Data1(sr, 1) ' number
                        Data2(dr, 1) = Data2(sr, 1) ' string
                    End If
                Next sr
                If dr > 0 Then
                    dcell.Resize(dr).Value = Data1
                    dcell.EntireRow.Columns(dCols(1)).Resize(dr).Value = Data2
                    Set dcell = dcell.Offset(dr)
                End If
            Next n
        End If
        Set sws = Nothing ' reset
        swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Filename = Dir
    Loop
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Data imported.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

**Help**

```vb
Function PickFolder( _
    Optional ByVal InitialFolderPath As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal DialogTitle As String = "Browse", _
    Optional ByVal DialogButtonName As String = "OK", _
    Optional ByVal CancelMessage As String = "") _
As String
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Pick Folder"
    
    With Application.FileDialog(4) ' 4 = msoFileDialogFolderPicker
        .Title = DialogTitle
        .ButtonName = DialogButtonName
        Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
        Dim FolderPath As String
        If Len(InitialFolderPath) > 0 Then
            FolderPath = InitialFolderPath
            If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then FolderPath = FolderPath & pSep
            .InitialFileName = FolderPath
        End If
        If .Show Then
            FolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
            If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then FolderPath = FolderPath & pSep
            PickFolder = FolderPath
        Else
            If Len(CancelMessage) > 0 Then
                MsgBox CancelMessage, vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

```vb
Function GetRangeSingleColumn( _
    ByVal singleRange As Range, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnIndex As Long = 1) _
As Variant
    
    If singleRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If ColumnIndex < 1 Then Exit Function
    If ColumnIndex > singleRange.Columns.Count Then Exit Function
    
    Dim Data() As Variant
    
    With singleRange.Columns(ColumnIndex)
        If .Rows.Count = 1 Then
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            Data = .Value
        End If
    End With

    GetRangeSingleColumn = Data

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  Sorry for the missing information earlier on

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow your VB's intention, is to **import** dataset from multi Excel files into *Data* sheet under "Master Tracker". Try the code below if may help a bit,

```vb
Sub importdata()
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim Message As String: Message = "Would you like to import new data?"
    Dim Ans
    Ans = MsgBox(Message, vbYesNo)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    If Ans = vbYes Then
        
        Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        With fldr
            .Title = "Select Current Data Sheet"
            .Show
            
            Dim FolderPath As String
            If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
                FolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
            Else
                MsgBox "Please select a file, even if it's the old one.  Otherwise, hit No on the first prompt"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End With
        
        FolderPath = fldr.SelectedItems(1)
        Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsx")
        
        Dim UNdest As Range
        Dim sell As Range
        Dim selloff As Range
        Dim copyrng As Range
        Dim destination As Range
        
        Set UNdest = Workbooks("Master Tracker").Sheets("Data").Range("AT2").End(xlDown).Offset(1)
        
        Do While Filename <> ""
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
            Set Sheet = ActiveSheet
            
            For Each sell In Sheet.Range("D:D")
                If IsNumeric(sell.Value) Then
                    Set selloff = sell.Offset(0, -1)
                    Set copyrng = Sheet.Range(sell, selloff)
                    Set destination = UNdest.Resize(copyrng.Rows.Count, 2)
                    destination.Value = copyrng.Value
                    Set UNdest = UNdest.Offset(copyrng.Rows.Count)
                End If
            Next sell
            
            Workbooks(Filename).Close SaveChanges:=False
            Filename = Dir()
        Loop
    
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: "guessing" your orig `Set copyrng = (sell:selloff)` uses a colon wrongly for string concatenation instead of defining a range, leading to a syntax error...

Comment: Thank you for the help on this.  This definitely got me closer to a solution.

Comment: @AdmBerner all good, glad you've got it sorted